# Subspaces of a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

The exercise is to prove that the set of complex numbers is a linear space over the field of complex numbers and to find two subspaces (not the trivial and the space itself). I was able to show the first part but i'm not able to find two subspaces (if there's any). I'd like a hint on how to approach the second part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no other subspaces of $\mathbb C$. This is because $\dim_\mathbb C(\mathbb C)=1$, so any subspace of $\mathbb C$ has either dimension $1$ or $0$. The latter case is the zero space, and the former case is the entire space $\mathbb C$.